# Call /userinfo from spring backend (auth0)

Tags: javascript, java, android, spring, auth0

I am attempting to do [this call](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#get-user-info) from my spring backend api. I already have the access token which the client sent me. What is the java-equivalent of this code?:

```
// Script uses auth0.js. See Remarks for details.
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0/9.0.1/auth0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Initialize the Auth0 client
  var webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain:       '{domain}',
    clientID:     '{clientId}'
  });

  // Parse the URL and extract the access_token
  webAuth.parseHash(window.location.hash, function(err, authResult) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    webAuth.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, function(err, user) {
        // This method will make a request to the /userinfo endpoint 
        // and return the user object, which contains the user's information, 
        // similar to the response below.
    });
  });
</script>
```

Details in access token from client (I removed some of the details and replaced them with square brackets):

```
~~~~~~~~~ JWT Header ~~~~~~~
JWT Header : {"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","kid":"[kid]"}
~~~~~~~~~ JWT Body ~~~~~~~
JWT Body : {"iss":"https://demo.auth0.com/","sub":"google-oauth2|[my id here]","aud":["[api audience]","https://demo.auth0.com/userinfo"],"iat":[number],"exp":[expiry],"azp":"[azp]","scope":"openid"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a standard `https` call (plus adding the access token as an authorization bearer header) - no special library required.

An example making this from server-side using Node.js is [here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-regular-webapp-login-with-sso-and-api/blob/master/routes/apis.js#L30).

Basic Java outline, here using OkHttp, would be:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://mytenant.auth0.com/userinfo")
  .get()
  .addHeader("authorization", "Bearer  {{access_token}}")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```